# How to eliminate Image overlapping in canvas(kineticjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am developing view of hotel floor using canvas with the help of kinetic js. But in that i am getting images overlapping each other in the canvas. help me out to eliminate that overlapping of images in the canvas.

[image]

this is my code:

```
// get a reference to the house icon in the toolbar
// hide the icon until its image has loaded
var $house=$("#house");
$house.hide();

// get the offset position of the kinetic container
var $stageContainer=$("#container");
var stageOffset=$stageContainer.offset();
var offsetX=stageOffset.left;
var offsetY=stageOffset.top;

// create the Kinetic.Stage and layer
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 350,
  height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

// start loading the image used in the draggable toolbar element
// this image will be used in a new Kinetic.Image
var image1=new Image();
image1.onload=function(){
  $house.show();
}
image1.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/4top.png";

// make the toolbar image draggable
$house.draggable({
  helper:'clone',
});

// set the data payload
$house.data("url","house.png"); // key-value pair
$house.data("width","32"); // key-value pair
$house.data("height","33"); // key-value pair
$house.data("image",image1); // key-value pair

// make the Kinetic Container a dropzone
$stageContainer.droppable({
  drop:dragDrop,
});

// handle a drop into the Kinetic container
function dragDrop(e,ui){

  // get the drop point
  var x=parseInt(ui.offset.left-offsetX);
  var y=parseInt(ui.offset.top-offsetY);

  // get the drop payload (here the payload is the image)
  var element=ui.draggable;
  var data=element.data("url");
  var theImage=element.data("image");

  // create a new Kinetic.Image at the drop point
  // be sure to adjust for any border width (here border==1)
  var image = new Kinetic.Image({
    name:data,
    x:x,
    y:y,
    image:theImage,
    draggable: true
  });
  layer.add(image);
  layer.draw();
}
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
#toolbar{
  width:350px;
  height:35px;
  border:solid 1px blue;
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h4>Drag from toolbar onto canvas. Then drag around canvas.</h4>
<div id="toolbar">
  <img id="house" width=32 height=32 src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/4top.png"><br>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Listen for the `dragstart` event on the object being dragged. In dragstart, save the starting x,y of this object. Also listen for the `dragend` event. In the dragend, do collision-tests of this image versus all other images to see if it intersects. If it intersects, you can set the x,y of this colliding object back to its starting x,y (or animate it back for a nicer effect).